# How to shorten a line but maintain its angle?

Tags: arithmetic, graphing-functions, slope

I have a line that looks like this:

[image]

to draw this line i have the following:

point A: (x,y)
point B: (x,y)

so for example, i will be given this path:

(90,20),(400,300)

and then i can draw a line because i know point A and B clearly.

Now my issue is the following:

i would like to shorten both ends of the line **but maintain its angle**.

I tried just subtracting manually a value from y position but its not always accurate. see the thing is the points i will be given ALWAYS make the line point to the center of the markers on the map. See how in the photo the line points directly to the center of the "B" marker.  so i just need to maintain its angle and i'll be fine.  So how can i shorten the line on both ends but still maintain the correct angle ?

the coordinate system i am using looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi & welcome to MSE. Here is a hint. [Equation of a Line from 2 Points](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html) shows how to create a simple equation describing the line. You can then adjust the value of $x$ or $y$ to determine the other value, i.e., $y$ or $x$.

Comment: Do you want to shorten both ends equally, or one more than the other?  How are you given the amount to shorten?

Comment: yes. i just want to shorten it slightly. i dont have an exact number . i'll play with it. can you help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the coordinates of $A$ are $(Ax,Ay)$ and of $B$ are $(Bx,By)$ the current length of the line is $$L=\sqrt{(Ax-Bx)^2+(Ay-By)^2}$$
You can parameterize the line as 
$$(Ax+t(Bx-Ax),Ay+t(By-Ay))$$
When $t=0$ you are at $A$ and when $t=1$ you are at $B$.  If you want to shorten the line, just go from, say, $t=0.1$ to $t=0.8$.  That will shorten the line by $10\%$ at the $A$ end and $20\%$ at the $B$ end.

Comment: i need the new coordinates to plot. this will give me the length.  i cannot use that.

Comment: You can compute them from whatever $t$ values you pick for the ends of the line.  Just plug those $t$s into the second expression.